# Why is Oracle RESULT_CACHE not reducing the number of LAST_CR_BUFFER gets?

Tags: oracle, caching, oracle11g

I'm doing some tests with the Oracle result_cache and came across something that looks strange (to me, anyway).

I've created the following table:

```
create table CACHE_TEST(
  COL1 int,
  COL2 int
);
```

And inserted some dummy data into it:

```
insert into CACHE_TEST select * from(
  select level as COL1, level*3 as COL2 from DUAL
  connect by level <= 100
);
```

Now I run an Autotrace on the following query:

```
select * from CACHE_TEST;
```

As expected, it shows a normal full table scan. I then run an Autotrace on the following query several times, and expect it to be using the result cache:

```
select /*+ RESULT_CACHE */ * from CACHE_TEST;
```

The Autotrace shows that it is indeed using the cache, but the number of buffer gets and cost is exactly the same as the first query.

Interestingly, if I do some kind of aggregate, eg:

```
select /*+ RESULT_CACHE */ AVG(COL1) FROM CACHE_TEST;
```

It reduces the buffer gets to zero, but the cost is still the same.

Can anyone explain why:

- The result cache doesn't seem to reduce the number of buffer gets unless you do an aggregate?
- Even when it does use the result cache the cost is still reportedly the same (even though I see a marked performance increase)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're selecting all the data from the table, why would you expect it to require fewer reads to read all that data from the table (which is likely completely in the buffer cache) rather than from the result cache?  Either way, you're reading the same number of blocks and getting the same amount of data back.

The result cache is really helpful when your query is doing some sort of expensive calculation.  That could be an aggregate-- reading a single cached value is obviously more efficient than reading every row from a table.  Or it could be a query that does a lot of work to figure out which subset of the table to read (joining through some other tables, for example).